# How to customize Create user wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, createuserwizard

I am using asp.net Create user wizard and I want to use the basic layout but just add to it additional controls. When I used Visual studio 2008 I remember that I had no problem just adding to the basic form but now I'm using VS 2010 and it seems that I can only either use the basic form or create a whole new form.

How can I take everything existing in the basic form and simply add on more?

Comment: How about a little Google search? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the smart tag pressing Edit Templates will give a totally empty template but pressing Customize create user step, leaves the orignal controls and format and enables adding additional controls.